# When exactly are devDependencies included into the angular build

Tags: angular, npm, package.json, build-dependencies, npm-build

I have an angular project that I build in two different ways - for two different environments (DEV and PROD; both on a corporate server)

Online I found different definitions of when the devDependencies (from package.json) are included into the build.

def1: only during local development -> not during runtime

def2: only when non-prod build

If definition 1 is accurate, then my question is obsolete.
However, if definition 2 is true, then my question would be:

Which of the two commands do qualify as a prod build?

```
ng build --base-href /appname/
ng build --prod --base-href /appname/
```

This question is resulting from the fact that some of my devDependencies have sub-dependencies that are rated as insecure (company internally). If the devDependencies are not shipped with any deployment (neither DEV nor PROD), there is no issue.

Answer (score 2):

The packages listed in the `devDependencies` section of `package.json` help you develop the application on your local machine. You don't deploy them with the production application.

build your production configuration using

```
ng build --prod --base-href /appname/
```

OR

```
 ng build --configuration=production --base-href /appname/
```

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
ng build --prod --base-href /appname/
```

is your prod build. When you run this build command your environment settings will be taken from the src/environments/environment.prod.ts file and stored within the application JavaScript output in the /dist output folder.